# Error 21 error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0004c7)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have a large windows forms project that was ported from MFC to WinForms.  The business logic is all in C++ so we have a couple of assemblies written using C++/CLI to wrap the unmanaged code.   The original port was done using Visual Studio 2005 and .net 2.1.  We have migrated it to VS2010 and .net 4.0.  We are currently maintaining both versions.  Everything was fine until I added a header file for a class so I could utilize one of its methods.  Just adding the header caused the error:

Error   21  error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0004c7).   c:\XXXX\Project\AAAAPI.obj
Project.API

There are two clases involve3 here:

AAAAAPI.cpp  with header AAAAAPI.h
BBBBAPI.cpp  with header BBBBAPI.h

if AAAAAPI only included AAAAPI.h
and BBBBAPI.cpp only includes BBBBAPI.h everything links and runs as expexcted

But when I add AAAAPI.h to BBBBAPI.cpp I get the above error.  What is interesting is it is not compalining about BBBAPI.OBJ but AAAAPI.OBJ

Also If I remove AAAAAPI.h from BBBBAPI.h (which works as above) and add BBBBAPI.H to AAAAPI.cpp it works.  So the same two headers in one cpp filr work and in another they do not work.

I hope this is enough information for you to understand my problem.  The code involved it part of a very large system and it would be difficult to add more detail about what the code is doing.  Just note that all I have to do is add a header file which is just a class definition, no executable code to cause the errors.

Any halp would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error when I had a #define that affected a class definition, and the class definition ended up different depending on which file it was included from. Check that you don't have any #defines or similar that might be affecting your classes.

You'll have to post code if you want a firmer answer. It's impossible to diagnose code issues without seeing the code.